# Cannot find a way to enable WiFi card on a 2012 Macbook Pro

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, macbook, macbook-pro

I have an early 2012 MacBook Pro ad cannot find a way to enable the WiFi radio. Linux Mint has it under drivers, but there is no such thing I can find on Ubuntu Studio.

I ran `lshw` and got this:

```
**-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetXtreme BCM57765 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0f0
       version: 10
       serial: 3c:07:54:1d:03:2e
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=5.15.0-43-lowlatency duplex=full firmware=57765-v1.37 ip=192.168.0.36 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:16 memory:a0400000-a040ffff memory:a0410000-a041ffff
  *-network
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=bcma-pci-bridge latency=0
       resources: irq:17 memory:a0600000-a0603fff*
```